# Data extraction from a list of tuples of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to retrieve the users data from my an appsflyer API and the output of the API is as follows:

**EDIT:**

**api.py** is where my dataclass was defined:

```
import dataclasses
import Optional

@dataclass
class user_api:
   id: str
   account: str
   email: Optional[str] = ""
   phone: field(repr = False)
   active: field(repr = False)
   state: field(repr = False)
```

**app.py**

```
import api
import requests

response = ('some code to authenticate the api and get data').json()

response_data = [getattr(api, appsflyer_endpoint)(**i) for i in response[appsflyer_endpoint]] 
#Here api is imported from above dataclass
```

I'm getting the below result when I print the `response_data`. I don't want to change the output format because this format is being used across different applications.

I just want to extract some specific fields from the final response

```
    [User(id = 1, account = 234, email='abc@gmail.com', 'phone':{'sms':2, 'email':2}, active: true),
     User(id = 2, account = 567, email='aaa@gmail.com', 'phone':{'sms':1, 'email':1}, active: true, state: 'NY'),
     User(id = 3, account = 890, email='aba@gmail.com', 'phone':{'sms':2, 'email':2}, active: true)
    ]
```

How can I extract the only particular fields from the above data i.e. `id, account and email`

The final output I'm expecting was

```
[User(id = 1, account = 234, email='abc@gmail.com'),
 User(id = 2, account = 567, email='aaa@gmail.com'),
 User(id = 3, account = 890, email='aba@gmail.com')]
```

I tried to extract its data from a tuple but didn't work. I'm not sure about this type of data format

Comment: can you share the API call then code until you print it ? where the User class comes from ?

Comment: @azro Ok, let me update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to exclude fields from the string representation of the `User` dataclass. That way the object will still have the "extra" attributes in the background. For example,

```py
@dataclass
class user_api:
   id: str
   account: str
   email: str
   phone: str = field(repr=False)
   active: str = field(repr=False)
   state: str = field(repr=False)
```

Comment: I used ```Optional`` (updated question). Is it possible to use field(repr = False) with that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package. It appears to help out with type hinting, so almost certainly.

Comment: I tried setting field(repr = False) for each unnecessary fields but when I print the final output I'm still seeing the additional fields

Comment: Interesting, it should. Can you show your code? Try copy and pasting the code chunk above and reinitiate the instances.

Comment: Gotcha, it was what I thought. Look carefully at your code vs mine.  Your version, `state: field(repr=False)` attempts to set the type hin of the state attribute to a field function. I'm guessing that if you are using a linter, it is pretty angry at that line, but it you aren't it is perfectly ok Python code. My version, `state: str = field(repr=False)` sets the type hint to the state attribute as a string, but its value is a field.